# How to "remove" mask from numpy array after performing operations?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a 2D numpy array that I need to mask based on a condition so that I can apply an operation to the masked array then revert the masked values back to the original.

For example:

```
import numpy as np

array = np.random.random((3,3))
condition = np.random.randint(0, 2, (3,3))
masked = np.ma.array(array, mask=condition)

masked += 2.0
```

But how can I change the masked values back to the original and "remove" the mask after applying a given operation to the masked array?

The reason why I need to do this is that I am generating a boolean array based on a set of conditions and I need to modify the elements of the array that satisfy the condition.

I could use boolean indexing to do this with a 1D array, but with the 2D array I need to retain its original shape ie. not return a 1D array with only the values satisfying the condition(s).

Comment: You can set `masked.mask = False` if you want to use masked variable and not original array one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You already have it: it's called `array`!

This is because while `masked` makes sure you only increment certain values in the matrix, the data is never actually copied.  So once your code executes, `array` has the elements at `condition` incremented, and the rest remain unchanged.

Comment: Great! For some reason I thought the masked array included only a copy of the original array and a mask. Thanks for your prompt reply!

Comment: @user2593236 - For what it's worth, the `np.ma.array` or `np.ma.masked_array` constructor takes an optional `copy` kwarg (that defaults to `False`).  If `copy=True`, then a copy is made.  If `copy=False`, then the original array is referenced, if possible.

Answer (score 10):

The accepted answer doesn't answer the question.  Assigning the mask to `False` works in some cases but with many algorithms that do not support masked arrays (e.g. [`scipy.linalg.lstsq()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.0/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.lstsq.html)) you will experience an error like this:

```
ValueError: masked arrays are not supported
```

You can test if you array has still the attribute mask like this:

```
import numpy as np

array = np.random.random((3,3))
condition = np.random.randint(0, 2, (3,3))
masked = np.ma.array(array, mask=condition)

masked += 2.0

masked.mask = False
hasattr(masked, 'mask')
>> True
```

The only way to really get rid of the mask is by assigning a variable only to the data of the masked array:

```
masked = masked.data 
hasattr(masked, 'mask')
>> False
```

Comment: @G.M. Wonderful answer. Really  helped me to get out of a tight spot